# Where can I find documentation for linux net event in `include/trace/events/net.h`?

Tags: linux, events, linux-kernel

I want to use bpf to intercept/inject to some events but I couldn't find documentation for them, like in this:

```c
//https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/trace/events/net.h#L143
DEFINE_EVENT(net_dev_template, net_dev_queue,

    TP_PROTO(struct sk_buff *skb),

    TP_ARGS(skb)
);
```

The event `net_dev_queue` is not described anywhere. Of course I can look in its format using `cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/net/net_dev_queue/format`

```sh
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/net/net_dev_queue/format
name: net_dev_queue
ID: 1355
format:
        field:unsigned short common_type;       offset:0;       size:2; signed:0;
        field:unsigned char common_flags;       offset:2;       size:1; signed:0;
        field:unsigned char common_preempt_count;       offset:3;       size:1; signed:0;
        field:int common_pid;   offset:4;       size:4; signed:1;

        field:void * skbaddr;   offset:8;       size:8; signed:0;
        field:unsigned int len; offset:16;      size:4; signed:0;
        field:__data_loc char[] name;   offset:20;      size:4; signed:1;

print fmt: "dev=%s skbaddr=%p len=%u", __get_str(name), REC->skbaddr, REC->len
```

... but I need more information.